# Projective dimension of $A$ over $B$ $\le$ projective dimension of $C$ over $B$?

Tags: ring-theory

If $C$ is an $B$-algebra and $A$ is a projective $C$-module, then does it follow that the projective dimension of $A$ over $B$ is less than or equal to the projective dimension of $C$ over $B$?

Comment: Don't delete your questions shortly after they have been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This is simply because $A$, being projective, will be a direct factor of a free $C$-module $F$.  If we write $F=A\oplus X$, then $\operatorname{proj.dim}_B(F) = \operatorname{max}(\operatorname{proj.dim}_B(A),\operatorname{proj.dim}_B(X))$.  Moreover, since $F$ is a direct sum of copies of $C$, then $\operatorname{proj.dim}_B(F) = \operatorname{proj.dim}_B(C)$.  So indeed we get
$$
\operatorname{proj.dim}_B(A) \leq \operatorname{proj.dim}_B(C).
$$